# Почему данные заказа не отображаются?

Tags: php, woocommerce

В личном кабинете woocommerce, при просмотре заказов по ссылке `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order` есть один заказ, в котором отсутствуют данные покупателя, но статус заказа "Выполнен".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
должно быть как-то так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У этого покупателя два заказа и если зайти в личный кабинет этого покупателя по ссылке `/account`, то отображается только один заказ, но по ссылке `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order` администратору показываются два заказа.
Что с первым заказом?  т.е. второй заказ отображается нормально, сделанный недавно, а 1й заказ сделанный в начале прошлого года не отображается в личном кабинете покупателя.
Из-за чего это может быть?  Как это проверить? Есть доступ к базе

В базе данных в таблице `woocommerce_order_items` эти два заказа есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в базе данных сравнить других пользователей и их заказы с этим пользователем. Возможно была какая-то ошибка и не хватает какой-то записи.

Comment: да, одно поле в базе было некорректно записано почему-то